# Spring Data Mongo Embedded test fails with "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'"

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My tests using Spring Data and embedded Mongo fail with "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'" which suggests the version of MongoDB is < 3.4 however I have specified v3.6 when setting up the tests and I can see from the logs that featureCompatibility is set correctly and the mongo db driver looks ok at version 3.6.4. When I run my code (not the test) against a standalone 3.6 instance of MongoDB it works as expected - just the tests with embedded flapdoodle mongo that fail. Any pointers please?

-- maven logs --

```
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.5
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a20ecd3e3a174162052ff99913bc2ca9a839d618
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27018 }, security: { authorization: "disabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/tmp/embedmongo-db-1cde0ab0-bb3d-4256-8e4c-19401c64337d", journal: { enabled: false }, mmapv1: { preallocDataFiles: false, smallFiles: true }, syncPeriodSecs: 0.0 } }
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:01.339+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
```

...

```
[mongod output] 2019-03-10T17:54:02.044+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.6
```

...

```
rg.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 16436: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'' on server localhost:43425. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'", "code" : 16436 }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16436: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'' on server localhost:43425. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'", "code" : 16436 }
        at team.teamservice.web.team.TeamRepositoryTest.findAncestors(TeamRepositoryTest.java:121)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16436: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'' on server localhost:43425. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'", "code" : 16436 }
        at team.teamservice.web.team.TeamRepositoryTest.findAncestors(TeamRepositoryTest.java:121)
```

-- test setup --

```
  @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException
        {

        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 27018;

        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.V3_6)
                .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
                .build();

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        mongodExecutable.start();
}
```

-- repository code --

```
@Override
public List<Team> findAncestors(String id)
    {

    TypedAggregation<Team> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Team.class,
            match(Criteria.where("id").is(id)),
            Aggregation.graphLookup("team")
                    .startWith("id")
                    .connectFrom("parentId")
                    .connectTo("id")
                    .as("ancestors"));

    AggregationResults<Team> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Team.class);

    List<Team> teams = result.getMappedResults();

    return teams;
    }
```

-- mvn dependency:tree --

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------< team:web >------------------------------
[INFO] Building web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ web ---
[INFO] team:web:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.6.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.0.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:3.0.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.25.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:jar:3.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-expression-processor:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:3.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.attoparser:attoparser:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile (optional)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.visualization:visualization-datasource:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r07:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] \- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    \- de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.process:jar:2.1.2:test
[INFO]       +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:test
[INFO]       +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.5.2:test
[INFO]       +- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.5.2:test
[INFO]       \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.18:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.749 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-10T18:04:13Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I was confusing spring boot auto configuration with manual non-spring configuration and ended up with two instances of mongodb running different versions on two different ports.

As long as you have an @DataMongoTest annotation on your test the embedded mongodb is automagically configured. Remove the embedded mongodb config from your test setup otherwise you'll end up with the parallel mongo versions running during the tests.

In order to change the version you just need to set some application properties:

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.6.4
spring.mongodb.embedded.features=no_http_interface_arg,only_with_ssl
```

See https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/223 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12575 for further details.

Comment: This solution also worked with version 4.0.3. I just had to add *only_with_ssl* to the features list.